# Why is heartbeat failing over from master to slave?

Tags: high-availability, heartbeat, pacemaker

OS: CentOS 6.6 x64
Heartbeat Package: heartbeat-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64

Steps:
 1. Power on master and slave.
 2. master: service heartbeat start
 3. wait till master has all resources and cluster ip address.
 4. master: service network restart
 5. master: service heartbeat stop
 6. master: service heartbeat start
 7. wait till master has all resources and cluster ip address.
 8. slave: service heartbeat start
Results: Slave also becomes the new master. I'm trying to understand why restarting the network is causing problem.



If I do this:
Steps:
 1. Power on master and slave.
 2. master: service heartbeat start
 3. slave: service heartbeat start
Results: Everything works fine.


I understand heartbeat is old and obsolete, but until the customer transition away from heartbeat, I still need to support it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say the question is not clear, the feeling is, that you described just a half of the story.

Comment: Let me see if I can clarify it some more.  With the first set of instructions, when I start heartbeat on the slave, it detects the master is down and automatically converts the slave into a master.  In the end, I now have two master; the original master and the new master.  With the second set of instructions, everything works fine and I have only one master and one slave.  So, I'm trying to understand why when performing the first set of instructions, a failover happens.